# How to make a box2d body follow a sine curve

Tags: c++, box2d, trigonometry, path-finding, sprite

I would like to make a sprite follow the path of a sin curve, using the SetVelocity(x,y) function.  At first this seemed simple to me, I made a function that returns the derivative of the function I would like to travel along, i.e. for sin(x) the function returns the cosine of that x.  The problem is that I use Time (c++ time_t) as the "x" in this equation.  When I return a result from this equation, I then have an X and a Y, and I use trig functions to get the ratio, i.e.

```
    float newY = velocityResults->getVelocityFromLua(x, functionToCall);

    float angle = std::atan2(newY,newX);
    float velocityX = cos(angle);
    float velocityY = sin(angle);
    velocityX*=PLAYER_SPEED;
    velocityY*=PLAYER_SPEED;
    player->getPhysicalProperties()->setVelocity(velocityX,velocityY);
```

The problem with this is that time increases more and more over time, and this, upon further inspection, is a horrible way to achieve my goal, as it does not work at all.  Time goes on and on and x gets bigger and bigger, so it overtakes everything.  I know there is a simpler way to do this but It is completely escaping me.

(Reason I'm doing this:  I'm making a math game where the player travels along different functions' paths to achieve a goal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `b2MouseJoint` and update it's target to be on your curve

Comment: I figured out a better way.  I return x*cosx from my call and this maintains an even ratio with the time.  Not sure if anyone will understand this but it makes sense.

Comment: I checked your answer because you were the only person to answer, but you didn't answer my question!  You just told me an entirely different way to do it.